# Health bar - calculating health bar's position from percentage

Tags: c#, unity, scripting

I'm making a simple health bar in Unity 3D. Health bar UI is made from images. I'm having a problem with setting bar's position based on health percentage.
Here's a script part:

```
    percentHealth = (currentHealth / maxHealth) * 100; //get's health percentage.

    HealthBarHealth.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(healthBarCurrentX, 0); //moves health bar
```

I want healthBarCurrentX to be calculated from these values:

percentHealth - percentage calculated from max health and current.
healthBarMaxX = 0f - health bar's position at 100% health.
healthBarMinX = -273.5f - bar's position at 0% health.

So when health is 50%, currentX is at -136.65, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Mathf.Lerp() to interpolate between the value you want at 0% and the value you want at 100%.

[Mathf.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html)

```
healthBarCurrentX = Mathf.Lerp(healthBarMinX, healthBarMaxX, currentHealth / maxHealth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a black bar, with a green bar painted on top of it. Just change length of the bar on top, and it should work well.

```
blackbarlength = 100;
percentHealth = (currentHealth / maxHealth) * 100;
greenbarlength =  percenthealth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Slider component of uGUI? Its very easy,flexible and resolution independent.Check in,
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-health